# Select multiple rows in different tables in one query

Tags: php, sql

I have multiple tables with almost the same data, one table for each week. I want to track the change every week so all tables has the same column. Is there a way to do a `SELECT * WHERE ItemName = exampleItem` on every table in one query?

Comment: you need to use join queries

Comment: use joins  .......

Comment: Use `SQL joining` You can get idea of joins from http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: **Database design error** Place all the data in a single table and then the job becomes easy. If searching your data becomes difficult, it normally should shout at you that you made a design mistake

Answer (score 1):

Use [joins](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

```
SELECT * table t1 left join table2 t2 on t2.someid = t1.someid  WHERE t1.ItemName = exampleItem
```

Answer (score 0):

If the structure is the same go for union all

```
select column1,column2...columnN from t1 where ItemName = exampleItem union all
select column1,column2...columnN from t2 where ItemName = exampleItem union all
...
select column1,column2...columnN from tN where ItemName = exampleItem;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try the following:

```
SELECT `row1` , `row2` ,`row3` FROM table1 AND `row1` , `row2` ,`row3` FROM table 2 WHERE `?`='?'
```